# SAS Segfault with plot= option in GENMOD

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use the genmod procedure in SAS, and keep getting segfault errors when I add more than one plot name to the "plots=" option.

My code is:

```
Ods graphics on;
Proc genmod data=library1.data1 plots=(Reschi(xbeta) leverageplot);
Class base_studyid nsaid (param=ref ref=first) pbqstatin (param=ref ref=first) hrtever (param=ref ref=first) timecls;
Model crp=time age e1baseline nsaid cholratio bfpbase hrtever time*e1baseline/wald type3;
Repeated subject=base_studyid/type=exch corrw covb withinsubject=timecls;
Run;
```

This code ran without errors until I added "leverageplot" to the "plots=" option. I've tried several other options in place of "leverageplot", with the same result-- which makes me think it's having a second plot in the "plots=" option that's causing trouble. Does anyone know how I can get multiple plots in GENMOD without a segfault?

Thanks very much!

Rachel

Answer (score 0):

An example from the SAS example library runs OK on my installation (9.3 TS1M1).  I do get a warning

```
1476  proc genmod data=nor plots=(Reschi(xbeta) leverageplot);
                                                ------------
                                                1
WARNING 1-322: Assuming the symbol LEVERAGE was misspelled as leverageplot.
```

Try changing your code to `leverage` instead of `leverageplot`.  Also try rearranging the order in which you specify the plots.  Older, experimental, versions of ODS GRAPHICS could be temperamental.